# SSIS ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Driver issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel

We have a SSIS package which is using a Excel destination. It was brought to my notice that the job was failing with the common error message 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered. I checked the server and could locate this driver in the registry. I exported the package into my local and execute it and it ran successfully. I thought of checking to rebuild the package again and test it from the server. Is there any other idea/solution? Please suggest.

Comment: Have you installed x32 or x64 drivers?

Answer (score 3):

A common cause of this problem can be the difference between 32 bit and 64 bit installations.

If your SSIS package is running in 64 bit the Access driver needs to be installed in 32 bit too.

My guess would be that on your machine you installed the 64 bit driver, but on the server the 32 bit driver has been installed.

You could test this by executing the package from the 32 bit dtexec found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\DTS\Binn
```

And trying to execute it from the 64 bit dtexec found here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\DTS\Binn
```

See the documentation for more information [dtexec Utility (SSIS Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx)

Then it's just a matter of installing the correct drivers (32 or 64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

When was the last time you updated the OS and SQL Server?

Back in the Fall, Microsoft deprecated OLEBD support for a short while, but then re-enabled its functionality after the community complained (and no doubt *tons* of SSIS and ETL packages and other apps failing.)

You can read the explanation and find out how to resolve the problem - here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2090199-microsoft-announces-that-ole-db-is-no-longer-deprecated